# How do I install IIS in Nano Server 1709 in Azure online

Tags: windows, iis, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016, windows-nano-server

I have an Azure VM running Nano Server 1709. I am trying to figure out how to install IIS on it, with little luck.

I have tried following the [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/nano-server) but I am unable to get remote access to the VM. I've opened ports 5985/5986 in the Network Security Group and the local machine firewall,but I still can't access it.

I tried executing the commands at the console of the VM and got this error:

```
PS C:\Windows> install-nanoserverpackage -name Microsoft-NanoServer-Storage-Package
install-nanoserverpackage : Add-WindowsPackage failed. Error code = 0x800f081e
At line:1 char:1
+ install-nanoserverpackage -name Microsoft-NanoServer-Storage-Package
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-NanoServerPackage
```

How can I install IIS with my one VM, either locally at the console or remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the instructions for Windows Server 2016 Nano Server.

Windows Server 1709 Nano Server is NOT an update/upgrade to Windows Server 2016.  It's the first product of the new Semi-Annual Release Channel.

Here's [some info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/semi-annual-channel-overview) on that.

Windows Server 1709 Nano Server can only be deployed as a container image, not a VM.  [Here's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/nano-in-semi-annual-channel) that info.

Once you have Windows Server 1709 Nano Server deployed to a container, [these](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/iis-on-nano-server) are the steps you have to follow to get IIS running in that environment (instructions start about a quarter of the page down).